# Can not connect docker containered postgres db

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:11
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5465:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgisdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p@ssword
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_test
```

Then I run `docker-compose up -d --build --remove-orphans`

`docker ps` shows:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                       NAMES
e7d734c1f23c   mdillon/postgis:11   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:5465->5432/tcp, :::5465->5432/tcp   app_db_1
```

When I try to connect database via pgadmin with parameters

```
Host name/address: localhost
Port: 5465
Maintence database: db_test
Username: user
Password: p@ssword
```

I still get error `password authentication failed for user "user"`.

What am I doing wrong?

Inside container env shows:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
HOSTNAME=bbc96a3254ed
PG_MAJOR=11
PWD=/
HOME=/root
PG_VERSION=11.2-1.pgdg90+1
GOSU_VERSION=1.11
PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
POSTGRES_DB=db_test
POSTGIS_MAJOR=2.5
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=p@ssword
POSTGRES_USER=user
SHLVL=1
POSTGIS_VERSION=2.5.2+dfsg-1~exp1.pgdg90+1
...
```

Comment: What is in the database log file?

Comment: Is pgadmin running in a container, or directly on the docker host?